# PWM signal not visible upon increasing the scope time base

Tags: pwm, oscilloscope, measurement, testing, frequency-measurement

I am capturing 2 different PWM signals.

The frequency of first PWM signal is lower when compared to the second one.

Please check the waveforms.

All the waveforms are taken of the same two signals. But upon increasing the time base, the second high frequency PWM signal vanishes like shown below.

Why is this happening?

Do I need to change some settings on the scope?

Oscilloscope : HDO6054A Teledyne Lecroy

[image]

[image]

[image]

**EDIT :
Issue solved if I use a different scope (Tektronix MDO3034)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope is running out of acquisition memory for the larger timebase and therefor has to reduce the sample rate. The reduced sample rate does not allow to capture the complete waveform of the fast PWM signal, because the Nyquist-Theorem is not fullfilled anymore. That's why the signal is displayed wrong.

Comment: The HDO6054A has a bandwidth of 500MHz as mentioned in the scope. But the frequency I am trying to measure is just around 120kHz. What settings should I change to get the waveforms in increased timebase itself? How to check the Acquisition memory of the scope?

Comment: The scope bandwidth is only the bandwidth of the analog front end and has nothing to do with the digital domain. If your timebase is large there simply is not enough memory to capture all the small details of fast signals that the analog front end with the high bandwidth passes through. I don't now the HDO6054A , maybe the memory depth is not controlled automatically and is not configured to maximum, but most scopes change that without user interaction. In that case the only things you can possible do is getting a scope with deeper memory or use a smaller timebase.

Comment: Ok. But usually in scope, if the Analog Bandwidth of a scope is mentioned Like 500MHz, I can properly measure an analog frequency of a maximum of 250MHz, theoretically, right? But in this scope, I am not able to do that at a high time base due it is poor memory size

Comment: Correct, you can use a scope for the highest frequencies only when timebase is short enough to store the high sample rate to memory.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @Newbie note the timebase in the bottom right corner. As you zoom out, its dropping the effective sample rate down to 2.5MS/s to cope with its internal memory buffer being only 2.5M samples deep.

Comment: @TomCarpenter - http://cdn.teledynelecroy.com/files/pdf/hdo6000a-oscilloscopes-datasheet.pdf . If you check this datasheet of my oscilloscop, the scope has provided "Long memory of 250Mpts/Ch" . But its lowest is only 2.5Mpts according to my scope waveforms. Why is this?

Comment: @Newbie only 50Mpt for all channels unless you've bought the XL memory option. As to why its recording only 2.5Mpt I don't know. Perhaps its configurable - what happens if you tap on the number?

Comment: When I tap on the 2.5MS, it allows me to choose the sampling rate. I can select a maximum Sampling rate of 10Ga/s. When I increase the sampling rate, it adjusts its time base automatically

Comment: And its mentioned in the datasheet as 50Mpt/ch for all channels in Standard variant itself. That means for each channel, my memory is 50Million samples right?

Comment: I have the option - L variant oscilloscope